# Where to define method to be accessible directly from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So idea is to define

```
def foo
  puts "Works!"
end
```

and directly from the console without loading anything I write

```
irb(main):001:0>foo()
=> "Works!"
irb(main):002:0>
```

I am using 1.9.3 on Windows. I want to use this in order to have a method which will reload lib/* so that I don't need to restart the console. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking... I have the following code in an initializer:

```
if defined?(Rails::Console)
  require "util/console_extensions"
  include ConsoleExtensions
end
```

and any extra methods I want in the console defined in `lib/util/console_extensions.rb`

```
module ConsoleExtensions
  def foo
    puts "Works!"
  end
end
```

This automatically requires and includes the `ConsoleExtension` module when loading the rails console and makes the methods defined in it available without the need to manually load anything.

Comment: Pure awesomeness! Thank you, very smart solution.

Comment: This does not work for me -- `Rails::Console` is not defined. First comment here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4604079/2339708) thinks it's because of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for testing purpose then define those files inside models :) and afterwords move them to lib directory